# Data import macro from .txt file really slow

Tags: excel

I have written a macro to open a .csv, copy over a few cells, then open a .txt and copy a few more.

The .csv runs really quickly, but it really bogs down on the .txt and sometimes crashes.

I am getting the "Waiting for another application to complete an OLE action" message twice, and think that is probably the issue but don't know how to troubleshoot that.

It does work, but would like it to run much faster.

Thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_Racecutter()
'
' Import_Racecutter Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = True

Dim source As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim newrow As ListRow
Dim pasteCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.item("Table2")

MsgBox "Select the RACECUTTER file to Import"

source = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=False)

If source = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected. Cannot continue."
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (source)

'On Error GoTo exit

Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add 'Insert new row at the bottom of the table

'Racecutter Data Merge
ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 5) 'TWS
ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 6) 'TWA
ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 7) 'AWS
ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 8) 'AWA
ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 9) 'BS
ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 10) 'HEEL
ActiveSheet.Range("B12").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 11) 'HS Load
ActiveSheet.Range("B19").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 12) 'MS Load
ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 13) 'Mast Rotation
ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 14) 'Traveler Position
ActiveSheet.Range("B15").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 15) 'V1 Port
ActiveSheet.Range("B16").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 16) 'V1 Stbd
ActiveSheet.Range("B17").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 17) 'D1 Port
ActiveSheet.Range("B18").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 18) 'D1 Stbd

ActiveWorkbook.Close
'Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Open Vspars File
MsgBox "Now select the VSpars file matching the Racecutter file you just opened"
source = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="TXT Files (.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=False)
Workbooks.OpenText source, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True

'VSpars Data Merge
'12.5%
ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 19) 'Camber
ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 20) 'Draft
ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 21) 'Front %
ActiveSheet.Range("F8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 22) 'Back %
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 23) 'Entry
ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 24) 'Exit
ActiveSheet.Range("G8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 25) 'Twist
'25%
ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 26) 'Camber
ActiveSheet.Range("D7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 27) 'Draft
ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 28) 'Front %
ActiveSheet.Range("F7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 29) 'Back %
ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 30) 'Entry
ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 31) 'Exit
ActiveSheet.Range("G7").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 32) 'Twist
'50%
ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 33) 'Camber
ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 34) 'Draft
ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 35) 'Front %
ActiveSheet.Range("F6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 36) 'Back %
ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 37) 'Entry
ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 38) 'Exit
ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 39) 'Twist
'75%
ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 40) 'Camber
ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 41) 'Draft
ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 42) 'Front %
ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 43) 'Back %
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 44) 'Entry
ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 45) 'Exit
ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 46) 'Twist
'87.5%
ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 47) 'Camber
ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 48) 'Draft
ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 49) 'Front %
ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 50) 'Back %
ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 51) 'Entry
ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 52) 'Exit
ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 53) 'Twist

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = False
'exit_:

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this website, the error can occur when reading data from non-excel files:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/excel-is-waiting-for-another-application

My guess is the text file is loaded in a less-efficient manner than normal excel or csv files and each copy action is forcing Excel to parse the text file to determine what data should be copied. Perhaps it would be quicker to copy all of the required data in one go to the current workbook on a temporary worksheet, and then copy the required values from there into the table.

Try adding a new worksheet to your workbook called "Temp", then you can do something like:

```
Dim wsTemp as Worksheet
Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
```

Then after opening the text file:

```
wsTemp.Range("A1:G8").Value = Activesheet.Range("A1:G8").Value
ThisWorkbook.Activate
wsTemp.Select
```

The rest of the code should then work as is. (Although it would be better to use references to the wsTemp than activating it first.)

Hopefully this single copy action for all of the data from the text file takes around the same time as an individual copy action in your current code. The copy between sheets within the workbook should be much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copying and pasting, which includes all formatting, simply copy the values directly by assignment:

Instead of:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range(1, 19) 'Camber
```

Use:

```
newrow.Range(1, 19) = ActiveSheet.Range("C8")
```

Comment: Michael, thanks this was helpful, and it does speed up the sheet, but sometimes it still bogs down and that always corresponds to the OLE error in case you know what might be causing that.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with reading data from the text file one cell at a time. My next possible solution is quite different, so I've posted a new answer.